# I deleted flite files from my app and now when i try to re-import them, i'm getting an error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So i deleted 3 flite voices from my app that i didn't need, to speed it up. But then i got errors that they were required so i tried putting them back in and although the files were gone and deleted, i got a `Could not copy [location] to [location]` error. How would I go about re-importing them without getting this error?

Anybody else had some similar before?

Comment: Regardless of the specific fix for this, this kind of thing is why you should use version control.  If you screw up, it's no big deal to revert back to a working version.

Answer (score 1):

Restore the original files back in the project folder, or remove the references to the files and find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't delete those files, just the references to them. Go to the project folder and delete them by hand, Xcode can't put them there because files with such names already exist in the folder

Answer (score 0):

It just means you need to change the import option to not use "copy", since they are already in the location they would be copied TO.

In the dialog box that comes up when the drag the files into XCode just make sure it's not set to copy.